# How to Identify a symmetric encryption algorithm

Tags: algorithm, security, encryption, base64, encryption-symmetric

In the process of a non graded holiday school assignment, I was given the text "**a2hxcGJ3ZXdsIHdqdWF3bGttbiBtYnVqcnRlcWNmIHV0ciBtbSB2c2p3IHh6IGxzdWd3aQ==**" that it is encrypted using with a symmetric encryption algorithm with a week password (up to 8 chars) and then hashed. I am asked to identify the algorithm, state the process and decrypt the text.

The original text has which from the the two **==** I suspected it was a Base64 encoding and after running it from a validator I was right so the output is "**khqpbwewl wjuawlkmn mbujrteqcf utr mm vsjw xz lsugwi**".

The problem is that I really don't know where to go from here and I am not able to find resources regarding how I am going to do it.

Can you give me some advice, guidelines, methodology, tools etc in order to investigate the solution?

ps. The Hash above does not contain sensitive information, it is for educational purposes only

Comment: If a real cryptographic algorithm was used like AES then you can't identify it by just looking at the encrypted data. Encrypted data is by definition indistinguishable from random data. You can only perform try-and error all combinations of algorithms that were mentioned and  combine them with the most popular passwords or a name (may be name of the school or the teacher or something like that)

Comment: https://www.guballa.de/vigenere-solver can break this one.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I just tried but I dont get something that makes sence :(

Comment: You need to set the language to English.

Comment: Thank you @DavidEisenstat you are right, I will try to find the theory behind it now.